# read integer from txt file C

Tags: c, pointers, variables

I tried to initialize my variables with reading them out from a file. However i struggle really hard to make something usefull without writing 50+ lines of Code. Maybe somebody can give me a hint how to deal with this.

my text file ist like:
Its guaranteed that after '=' always follows an integer(maybe some whitespace) but never smth else.

a=12

b=  4
c  = 14

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void getAB(int *a, int*){
FILE *file;
file = fopen("file.conf", "r");
// read a and b an their content from file.conf

fclose(file);
return;
}



int main(){
int a,b;
getAB(&a, &b);

printf("A = %i B = %i\n",a, b);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at fscanf? It's good for reading data with a well-defined format. https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Comment: Oh sorry Monica i will try to express myself better in future :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using fscanf(),

> The fscanf() function is used to read formatted input from the file.
> It works just like scanf() function but instead of reading data from
> the standard input it reads the data from the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> // strerror
#include <errno.h>  // errno
#include <err.h>    // errx


FILE *file_open(void);
void getAB(int *, int *);

FILE *fp = NULL;

int
main(void)
{
    int a, b;

    getAB(&a, &b);
    
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

// open a file to read
FILE
*file_open(void)
{   
    extern FILE *fp;
    

    if ((fp = fopen("file.conf", "r")) == NULL)
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", strerror(errno));

    return fp;
}


void
getAB(int *a, int *b)
{
    extern FILE *fp;

    fp = file_open();
    
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d %d", a, b) == 2)
        printf("A = %i, B = %i\n", *a, *b);
    
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yeah, that makes more sense. and I'm using gcc compiler.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oh yeah..
Sorry I'm not an expert, I 'learned' about errno.h or err.h not long ago. But thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

And the reason I used err.h was because... umm there was a warning.

Comment: I do not use `errx()` as is is not standard C code, yet it is a nice extension provided by the compiler's library that was used well here to help deal with error handling.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - Yes, it seems like a very nice extension even though it is not part of the C standard. (maybe I should read a book, and get familiar with extensions, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf` is the right tools for this job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void getAB(int *a, int *b)
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("file.conf", "r");
    fscanf(file, " a = %d ", a);
    fscanf(file, " b = %d ", b);
    fclose(file);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    getAB(&a, &b);
    printf("A = %i B = %i\n",a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Non-standard `<unistd.h>, <sys/types.h>` not needed here.

Comment: Ahh nice thank you :D In case i would like to read an unknown format it but its guaranted that after '='  an integer follows, how could i do that ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @BroBot, but if you want a `scanf` format tat doesn't care what is to the left of the `=`, use `fscanf(file," %*s = %d ",&value);`